# How to get Typescript as either FileCodeModel or (Roslyn) Document with working GetSyntaxRoot in VSIX

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

Title is pretty much it. I need to be able to parse the syntax of a document to figure out what a user right clicked on to take my action. I am not manipulating the document so I really only need something that can get me the syntax node or equivalent. I have this working with C# and VB already but cannot figure out any part of the VSSDK or Roslyn SDK that can get me any kind of syntax tree for typescript.

Example of how I do it with the other languages with Roslyn, I have other code that works with the FileCodeModels so if I could get that it would also be fine for me to work with.

I'm actually thinking that I need to tap into the TypeScript Extension installed into VS (create extension dependency) but am not really sure.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextView textView = GetTextView();
if (textView != null)
{
                SnapshotPoint caretPosition = textView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
                Document document = caretPosition.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
                if (document != null)
                {
                    SyntaxToken? token = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result?.FindToken(caretPosition);                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is neither a Roslyn `SyntaxTree` nor a `FileCodeModel` for TypeScript code, partly because the TypeScript engine is written itself in TypeScript, so there aren't managed representations to speak of. TypeScript's IDE experience internally uses a bit of Roslyn, which is why you see there's a Document available for you to grab, but there's no syntax tree from there to use.

Comment: And there currently is no easy way to get access to the TypeScript engine. Can you file a bug with your scenario on the TypeScript GitHub page?

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a bug but I would definitely post it somewhere for a feature request or discussion. I'm not a big gitHub user, could someone point me to the right forum/url/tracker to put it up?

Comment: Also I'll give you the answer cred in a few days just to make sure someone does not have some magical idea.

Comment: I put it here, hope its correct -> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9087

Comment: They responded with https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6508

Apparently they are working on opening it up for extensibility.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Jason Malinowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972216/jason-malinowski) stated, you cannot retrieve Roslyn SyntaxTree or FileCodeModel, but you can use [Javascript.NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) to run the [typescriptServices](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescriptServices.js) and communicate with it through a JavaScriptContext. If you are interested you can look at [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/tree/b0838faf2d4b0c19003039cd48ae8cc49768f30f/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/TypeScript/Project)'s implementation.